# CSV data into a 2D array of integers

Tags: c++, arrays, csv, converters

I have a .csv file with integers in two columns and many rows. It looks like this:

```
    A      B
1  584    146
2  586    167
.   .      .
.   .      .
```

I want to create a 2D array of integers from this .csv file in C++. I've searched dozens of websites but all of the answers I could get was with strings.

This is how the raw data looks like:

```
584,146
586,167
588,189
```

Comment: You will want to look at `std::vector` and `std::stoi`.

Comment: Just take the csv fields as string and then use [std::stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) to parse the strings to integer.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ read file comma separated array" or "C++ read file comma separated vector".

Answer (score 3):

The easy way to approach the problem is to recognize that you can read the entire line, and then iterate over the line as a `stringstream` using `getline` with a `','` as the delimiter to separate the values.

(`stringstream` is required, you can't simply separate the values while reading the line itself with `getline` -- there would be no obvious end of read at the end of the line -- you would simply read the next value beginning on the next line)

However, if you read the line first, create a stream, and then parse the stream, the read stops at the end of the stream providing you a way to detect the last value in a row, e.g. using a vector to store the values converted to `int` with `std::stoi`, you could fill each row vector as follows:

```
    std::string line, val;                  /* string for line & value */
    ...
    while (std::getline (f, line)) {        /* read each line */
        std::vector<int> v;                 /* row vector v */
        std::stringstream s (line);         /* stringstream line */
        while (getline (s, val, ','))       /* get each value (',' delimited) */
            v.push_back (std::stoi (val));  /* add to row vector */
```

For your "2D" array use, you actually want a `vector` of `row vectors` or a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. So declaring your array as:

```
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> array;    /* vector of vector<int>  */
```

you can complete your read of row into the array simply by pushing each row vector `v` back into your `array`, e.g. (with declarations and loop in context)

```
    std::string line, val;                  /* string for line & value */
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> array;    /* vector of vector<int>  */

    while (std::getline (f, line)) {        /* read each line */
        std::vector<int> v;                 /* row vector v */
        std::stringstream s (line);         /* stringstream line */
        while (getline (s, val, ','))       /* get each value (',' delimited) */
            v.push_back (std::stoi (val));  /* add to row vector */
        array.push_back (v);                /* add row vector to array */
    }
```

All that remains is accessing each value so you can make use of them. The range-based loop provides just what you need (actually a nested pair of range based loops, one to iterate over the vectors, the second to iterate over values. For example, you could do:

```
    for (auto& row : array) {               /* iterate over rows */
        for (auto& val : row)               /* iterate over vals */
            std::cout << val << "  ";       /* output value      */
        std::cout << "\n";                  /* tidy up with '\n' */
    }
```

Putting all the pieces of the puzzle together, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    std::ifstream f;

    if (argc > 1) {         /* if argument given */
        f.open (argv[1]);   /* open file with filename as argument */
        if (! f.is_open()) {    /* validate file open for reading */
            std::cerr << "error: file open failed '" << argv[1] << "'.\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {  /* no argument given, error show usage */
        std::cerr << "error: insufficient input. <filename> required.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string line, val;                  /* string for line & value */
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> array;    /* vector of vector<int>  */

    while (std::getline (f, line)) {        /* read each line */
        std::vector<int> v;                 /* row vector v */
        std::stringstream s (line);         /* stringstream line */
        while (getline (s, val, ','))       /* get each value (',' delimited) */
            v.push_back (std::stoi (val));  /* add to row vector */
        array.push_back (v);                /* add row vector to array */
    }

    for (auto& row : array) {               /* iterate over rows */
        for (auto& val : row)               /* iterate over vals */
            std::cout << val << "  ";       /* output value      */
        std::cout << "\n";                  /* tidy up with '\n' */
    }
}
```

**Example Input File**

Which given your input file of:

```
$ cat dat/nums.csv
584,146
586,167
588,189
```

**Example Use/Output**

It would be parsed and stored as a vector of integer vectors (providing plain-old 2D array access).

```
$ /bin/vect2d_strstream dat/nums.csv
584  146
586  167
588  189
```

Look things over and let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with reading each line with `std::getline`, store the line in a `std::stringstream`, then read the individual tokens using the overloaded `std::getline` that takes a delimiter.

You can then parse these tokens to integers using `std::stoi`, and store them in a `std::vector< std::pair<int, int> >`.

A good explanation with a working code sample can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120224/4723238).